# Extraer segunda ocurrencia del elemento <strong> de una expresión HMTL

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath

Tengo la siguiente expresión `HTML`

```
$text = '<strong>Aqui</strong> tengo el elemento <strong>PRIMERO</strong> y el <strong>SEGUNDO</strong>'
```

Necesito extraer de esta expresión el segundo elemento entre las etiquetas `<strong>`, o sea, el texto **`PRIMERO`**

He probado con `DOMXPath::evaluate` pero me devuelve la primera ocurrencia

```html
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($text);
$xpath = new DomXPath($doc);
$resultado = $xpath->evaluate("string(//strong)");
```

El resultado es `Aquí`

He probado con `DOMXPath::query` y lo único que obtengo es el número de ocurrencias (3)

```html
$text = '<strong>Aqui</strong> tengo el elemento <strong>PRIMERO</strong> y el <strong>SEGUNDO</strong>';
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($text);
$xpath = new DomXPath($doc);
$resultado = $xpath->query("//strong");

----

object(DOMNodeList)#6 (1) {
  ["length"]=>
  int(3)
}
```

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizando `xpath` puedes usar la sintaxis `//expresion[X]` donde `X` es la **ocurrencia número X**.

#### Ejemplo:

```
<?php

$text = '<strong>Aqui</strong> tengo el elemento <strong>PRIMERO</strong> y el <strong>SEGUNDO</strong>';
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($text);
$xpath = new DomXPath($doc);
$resultado = $xpath->query("//strong[2]");
var_dump($resultado[0]->textContent);
```

#### Salida:

```
string(7) "PRIMERO"
```

<kbd>[`Demo`](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/57931345aa5da506d74f17c7a7205e91277e37bd)</kbd>

Comment: Interesante, y que pasa si coloca `$resultado = $xpath->query("//strong[0]");`? que hay ahí? probé en el sandbox, sale error, por que se cuenta desde 1 y no 0?

Comment: @the-breaker exacto, cuenta desde 1 a N

Answer (score 2):

Con la clase `DOMDocument` es mas que suficiente, por ejemplo puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
<?php
// Nuestra cadena html
$text = '<strong>Aqui</strong> tengo el elemento <strong>PRIMERO</strong> y el <strong>SEGUNDO</strong>';
// instanciamos la clase
$doc = new DOMDocument();
// cargamos el string html
$doc->loadHTML($text);

// Acceder directamente a los valores, getElementsByTagName retorna un array de objetos
// con textContent recuperas el contenido como texto
echo $doc->getElementsByTagName('strong')[0]->textContent; // Aqui
echo $doc->getElementsByTagName('strong')[1]->textContent; // PRIMERO
echo $doc->getElementsByTagName('strong')[2]->textContent; // SEGUNDO

// Recorrerlos todos
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('strong') as $key => $value) {
    echo 'Clave: '. $key;
    echo ', Valor: '.$value->textContent.PHP_EOL;
}
// Resultado
/*
Clave: 0, Valor: Aqui
Clave: 1, Valor: PRIMERO
Clave: 2, Valor: SEGUNDO
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hice este codigo para resolver el problema.**

En cuanto a la concurrencia si remueves el nodo `<strong>` queda ese espacio vacio por lo que lo mas practico usando la clase DOMDocument es reemplazar por otra etiqueta.

La variable $id indica la posicion de concurrencia a la cual quieres cambiar
La variavle $etiquetaBuscar es la etiqueta HTML a buscar
La variable $etiquetaReemplazar se coloca el HTML que va a cambiar

Aqui esta el codigo:

```
<?php

    $text = '<strong>Aqui</strong> tengo el elemento <strong>PRIMERO</strong> y el <strong>SEGUNDO</strong>';

    // carga de nodo
    $dom = new DOMDocument; 
    $dom->loadHTML($text); 
    $xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);


    $id = 1;                      // posicion del nodo a cambiar
    $etiquetaReemplazar = "span"; // etiqueta a colocar span
    $etiquetaBuscar ='strong';    // etiqueta a reemplazar

     // nodo a buscar
     $nodes = $xPath->query('//'.'strong'); 

    // nuevo nodo
    $frag =  $dom->createElement($etiquetaReemplazar); 
    $contenido =  $nodes->item($id)->textContent;
    $fragA = $dom->createTextNode($contenido);
    $frag->appendChild($fragA);

    // reemplazar nodo
    if($nodes->item($id)) { 
        $nodes->item($id)->parentNode->replaceChild($fragA, $nodes->item($id));
        } 
    $html = $dom->saveHTML();

    // salida
    echo $html;

?>
```

La salida es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]